# Should 'r.pause_threshold' be defined one time or for every listen?

Tags: python, timeout, speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-to-text-api

In many voice recognition codes I can see that `pause_threshold` is configured inside a `while` loop.
I believe it should be defined only once outside the `while True` loop. Is that correct?

```py
while True:
    if working == True:
         
        with sr.Microphone() as source: 
            
            r.pause_threshold=0.5
            audio = r.listen(source)
            queue.put(audio)
```